# AVD/SDK Manager not running (Windows 7 Java 1.7.0_40)

Tags: java, android, windows, eclipse

I'm trying to run the SDK/AVD Manager on my computer but a cmd window pops up for a moment before disappearing, I've been trying solutions to similar if not identical problems for a while now and have had no such luck.

**Environment variables:**

- *CLASSPATH* = "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin"
- JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin"
- *Path* = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin;"
- *ComSpec* = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools"

**Solutions I've tried:**

- Uninstalling & reinstalling the Android SDK.
- The above as well as uninstalling & reinstalling Eclipse and the ADT plug-in.
- Changing Path variables and there order etc.
- Uninstalling & reinstalling Java and the JDK.
- Certain solutions which involve editing *android.bat* so that it points to my *java.exe* in the JDK.
- Uninstalling the SDK and reinstalling through the Android ADT bundle to see  if that would work. (No luck and after that I reason it must be the JDK or my system and not the Android SDK)

Ofcourse none of these solutions that have been recomended to me have worked, I'll list some debug information as well.

**Debug information:**

- Entering "where java" into the command line outputs "*C:\Windows\System32\java.exe C:\Program Files\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\java.exe*". (I understand if *System32\java* appears before the JDK in the Path variable that can cause issues, but as you can see above that is not the case)
- Moving to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools" in my command line and running "android.bat" gives out the error "'C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\lib\find_java.exe -s' is not recognized as
  an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file."
- As well as "
  ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
  Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
  We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads
  If you already have Java installed, you can define the JAVA_HOME environment
  variable in Control Panel / System / Avanced System Settings to point to the
  JDK folder."

Obviously I've had no luck with is problem, so my apologies if I have some n00b'ish error of my own fault and a thank you for any contribution to the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

Then I learned that the current version of ADT (adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030.zip) is not compatible with Java 1.7 .

So I downloaded and installed JDK 1.6 from here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u45-oth-JPR

Finaly I have created a small batch file to start eclipse:

```
path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;%PATH%
eclipse.exe
```

and saved it as `adt.bat` .

This makes sure that Java 6 is in front of Java 7 in your path.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the ADT bundle for windows from the below URL.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

You can download the entire bundle from here including SDK & eclipse with builtin plugin.

Comment: I tried this and it still had the exact same issue when I tried to run the SDK manager, thank you though.

Comment: You are using 64 bit machine. But you downloaded the SDK for 32 bit. Download the ADT bundle for 64 bit.

Comment: I installed the ADT bundle 64 Bit, I'm still having the same issues even with the fresh SDK that comes with it, although AVD manager is working strangely enough.

Comment: Make sure that you installed 64 bit version of java and the class path set. In the below line you are pointing to 32 bit version of java. ComSpec = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\;

Comment: I double checked, my java is 64 bit and I'm using the right JDK, still haven't got a clue what the problem is

Comment: Could Java 7 be a problem? Can you make sure you have only one JDK installed?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the Sdk folder
2. In the sdk folder open the tools folder
3. Open android.bat file
   A black screen will appear then sdk manager will be loaded